# Appium test not starting app on Android

Tags: android, appium

I have to learn about Appium and I am doing a "hello Appium".

Windows8, Appium 1.4.13.1 ,IntelliJidea 14.1

```
        WebDriver driver;
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"5554:Nexus_5");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "5.1");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,"C:\\Users\\demitria\\Desktop\\testapp.apk");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

            @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            driver.quit();
        }



        @Test
        public void tapOnLoginNotFilledAnyThing(){

            WebElement mob = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.testapp:id/login_login_button"));

          //here on mob WebElement I get java.lang.NullPointerException
         //at MyFirstTest.tapOnLoginNotFilledAnyThing(MyFirstTest.java:78)

          mob.click();
        }


        @Test
        public void logInWithInvalidEmail(){


        }
```

On appium I have the application path to
                                       C:\Users\demitria\Desktop\testapp.apk

Appium works well also the Appium inspector but when I launch the test nothing happen with the emulator(in the sense that the app is not started in the emulator) but in fact the test are executed or at least I think so. I get an alert icons as well on IntelliJidea . Any idea about what I´m doing wrong

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it giving instrumentation failure? Capabilities seem to be fine, check the app's launch able activity name with `aapt dump badging testapp.apk ` from `sdk\build-tools\<api-level>`.

Comment: @Demetria what is the error ?

Comment: @Shamik thanks !!  So I have discover one error more so i have two errors:

1.- java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MyFirstTest.tapOnLoginNotFilledAnyThing(MyFirstTest.java:68)

2. I´m wacthing in all tutorials than after to launch the test , the app starts to run on the emulator, but this is not my case , nothing happen on the emulator when I run the test

Comment: Post all the code. Taponlogin method and others.

Comment: @mk08  I have found aapt but after click on it , is visible just for a few moments ( less than 1 second) and after that is not visible anymore

Comment: @Demetria : Open the command prompt and go till `api-level` path. Something like this : `D:\Android\sdk\build-tool\19.0.1>aapt dump badging testapp.apk`

Comment: @Shamik I have edited my question with all the code

Comment: @Demetria AFAIK you have to specify the emulator using this key "avd". Please check this https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

Comment: @Demetria Put 

capabilities.setCapability("avd","5554:Nexus_5");

instead of the devicename. Ofcourse your AVD name should be that.

Comment: @Shamik the emulator is launched . I have  changed to  setCapability("avd","5554:Nexus_5"); but still getting the  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Demetria can you run this command in your shell .  adb shell am start -n com.example.testapp/.activities.LoginActivity    Does this launch the app?

Comment: @Shamik  Yes It does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95428/discussion-between-shamik-and-demetria).

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

1.- Uninstall IntelliJidea 14.1 and install Eclipse (the current version), it gives me more information about the errors I have than IntelliJ (you can omit this steep)
2.- Move my .apk to-> sdk\build-tools\ApiVersionYouAreUsingInAppium, my case C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1
3.- Set the new path on Appium-> Android Setting-> your aplication path

Modify Capacibilities as show below

```
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

     DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

     File appDir = new File("C:\\Android\\sdk\\build-tools\\22.0.1\\");
     File app = new File(appDir, "testapp.apk");

     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Nexus_5");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "5.1");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"Android");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.example.testapp");
     capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"com.example.testapp.MainActivity");

     driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the modified capabilities a shown below.

```
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"5554:Nexus_5");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "5.1");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,"C:\\Users\\demitria\\Desktop\\testapp.apk");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

If you have the APK file with you when you set the `MobileCapabilityType.APP` capability Appium automatically opens the main activity of the app while running.

Comment: Please share your error stack trace (Appium Console and junit console output) from the execution.

Comment: On IntelliJ 

java.lang.NullPointerException at MyFirstTest.tapOnLoginNotFilledAnyThing(MyFirstTest.java:68)

On appium console all is working well

Comment: Replace your setup method with the setup method i have updated in the answer.  Also can you point to the exact line of code where you are getting the nullpointer in the posted code.